# Is the tangent space at a point on a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

I am confused about the exact "type" (to borrow from computer science terminology) that tangent spaces have. Let's say I have a sphere $S$ in $\mathbb R^3$, and a tangent space $T_xS$ at some point $x$ on the sphere. Now, here is what I am wondering: is $T_xS$ a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ containing 3-vectors, or is it $\mathbb R^2$, containing 2-vectors? Obviously both choices are isomorphic, but the difference is important if specific elements of the tangent space are to be written down on paper.

Comment: I'd say definitely not $\mathbb R^2$. Some authors define such a tangent space so that it is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: If $U\in\mathbb R^2$ is open and $f:U\to S\in\mathbb R^3$ is a local parametrization of $S$ with $f(u)=x$ then my definition of tangent space would be $\mathrm TS_x=\mathrm df_u(\mathbb R^2)$ which is indeed a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: The way it is usually defined formally, the answer would be neither.

Comment: @EricWofsey What would it be, then?

Comment: Well there are a variety of different and essentially equivalent definitions that are used, but one common one is that an element of the tangent space is a certain set of curves (all the curves through the point that have a given tangent vector).

Comment: @EricWofsey If it was a set of curves, would it then be a vector space at all?

Comment: Yes, though the definition of the vector space structure is a bit complicated.

Comment: In any case, the tangent space at any point can certainly be considered as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in a canonical way.  It's not clear to me what you are looking for with your question, though.  What do you mean by "write down on paper"?

Comment: I thought the tangent space for a point $p$ on the sphere is just $\{u\in \mathbb R^3:\langle u,p\rangle=0\}$ which is a $2$  dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Or more abstractly I guess, since $S=f^{-1}(0)$ where $f(x)=\|x\|-1,\ T_pS$  is the kernel of $d_pf$

Comment: @EricWofsey is referring to the abstract definition of a smooth manifold, but if OP is reading a book such as Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres or Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak then a more concrete definition of a tangent space is usually used.

Comment: For "intuitive" definitions of the tangent space of a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2982185, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3512674 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3503836.